# Python - sccope of list variables

Tags: python, list, variables, scope

I wish to understand things better, why is this working without declaring list c as a global within the function fct?  The same is not true for variable a ?

```
def fct():
    global a      # have to declare this for "a" to work, but not for c[]
    print(a,c)    # by not declaring "a" as global, caused this to flag
                  # "accessing a without assignment", which I understand why,
                  # but why c[] needn't declaration
    c[1]=5
    a=234

c=[0,0]
a=11
fct()
```

Comment: You are not assigning to `c`. You are *mutating* `c` by telling *it* to set values for a given index. In other words, `c[...] = ...` differs materially from `c = ...`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules

Comment: The short answer is because lists are mutable and integers are immutable.

Comment: @Anup That's missing the point. As Martijn said, it's because you are _only_ mutating the list. But even if it is mutable, if you did `c = ...`, you'd need `global c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this question might need a little bit of explaining.

[PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) states that:

> In most languages that support nested scopes, code can refer to or rebind (assign to) any name in the nearest enclosing scope. Currently, Python code can refer to a name in any enclosing scope, but it can only rebind names in two scopes: the local scope (by simple assignment) or the module-global scope (using a global declaration).

Two things you must understand here is that:

- Binding: create a name, bind a value to it.
  **e.g**:`>>> a=10`
  creates a variable a and assigns 10 to it.
- Rebinding: change the value bound to the name.
  **e.g**:
  `>>> a=10;a=5`
  binds value 10 then rebinds 5 to 'a' itself.

So as it is clearly stated it can only rebind name in the local scope.

Example:

```
def func():
    a=5
    print(a)
a=10
print("a in the program")
print(a)
print("a in func()")
func()
```

output:

```
a in the program
10
a in func()
5
```

Now remove `a=5` from `func()` and you get:

```
a in the program
10
a in func()
10
```

What happens is `a` is found out to be `10` and it is printed.

Now do this:

```
def func():
    print(a)
    a=5
a=10
print("a in the program")
print(a)
print("a in func()")
func()
```

you get this:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

What happens if you give `a=5` in a function?

No *rebinding* occurs now instead a new local variable a=5 is created.

So,

- if you don't write `a=5` after/before `print` statement it just prints the global variable `a` by default.
- However if you write `a=5` before `print(a)` it creates a **local variable** `a` and then binds (note: not rebind but binds) the value `5` to it.
- **But** if you write `a=5` after `print(a)` it gets confused as to why you are referencing a variable(*local variable a*) which hasn't yet been created.

> However, because any assignment to a name implicitly declares that name to be local, it is impossible to rebind a name in an outer scope (except when a global declaration forces the name to be global).

So if you use `global a` the print(a) happily prints the global `a` as `10` and then creates a new local variable `a=5` by binding 5 to a.

```
global a
print(a)
a=5
print(a)
```

output:

```
def func():
    global a
    print(a)
    a=5
    print(a)
a=10
print("a in the program")
print(a)
print("a in func()")
func()
```

But this is not the case with your other objects like `list`,`dict` and such.
In this case, you're just modifying an existing, global object, which is found by regular name lookup (changing a list entry is like calling a member function on the list, it's not a name rebinding).

So it works fine without any errors. Hope you understood something.

Comment: That explains why `global a` is required; but OP asked why `global c` is _not_ required.

Answer (score 0):

If you use word `global` it means that you can write on a global variable, but I you just want to read it you don't need to use `global`.

You do not need to declare `c` and `a` in the function body because you have declared them just before execution of `fct()`

Comment: Thank you for pointing the finer points of binding to "c" the list as against changing one of its members.